# Button Icon centered horizontally but not vertically

Tags: html, css

I create a button using this code:

```
<div>
  <button class="btn nodeContainerBtn">
    <img class="btnIcon" src="Icons/icon-delete.png" />
  </button>
</div>
```

```css
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #E45043;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btnIcon{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nodeContainerBtn {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

So my Icon is centered horizontally but not vertically. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: The simplest way would be to add a couple of pixels of padding to the `img`, although that will only work if the button is a fixed height

Comment: Also note that I removed any references to JS/jQuery as it's irrelevant to the CSS issue you have

Comment: just add a margin:auto; style to the img

Comment: no, margin:auto does not fix it

Comment: What have you tried so far for centering vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to vertically align it.

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0):

giving some padding to `.btn` and `vertical-align` to `.btnIcon` seems to do it.

```css
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #E45043;
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding: 4px;
}

.btnIcon{
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.nodeContainerBtn {
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn nodeContainerBtn">
<img class="btnIcon" src="Icons/icon-delete.png" />
  </button>
</div>
```